# Drawing a charged ring xyz plane

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw this for one of my reports. But I don't know how to.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. I suggest to draw your picture using this tool online: https://www.mathcha.io/editor

Comment: You can also use Asymptote code to draw such images in the future. Asymptote is recognisable in a LaTeX compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I donate to you the ring uniformly charged using Mathcha previously indicated in  my comment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering


\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,444); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 444

%Shape: Arc [id:dp796341774674139] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0] (262.37,163.17) .. controls (263.64,157.97) and (266.21,153.41) .. (269.66,149.76) -- (291.5,170.33) -- cycle ; \draw   (262.37,163.17) .. controls (263.64,157.97) and (266.21,153.41) .. (269.66,149.76) ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp46939057871839585] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0] (356.12,162.23) .. controls (355.71,167.57) and (353.93,172.5) .. (351.13,176.67) -- (326.2,159.96) -- cycle ; \draw   (356.12,162.23) .. controls (355.71,167.57) and (353.93,172.5) .. (351.13,176.67) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da14186153692575143] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]    (308.75,164) -- (388.71,187.9) ;
\draw [shift={(393.5,189.33)}, rotate = 196.64] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (14.29,-6.86) -- (0,0) -- (14.29,6.86) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da24228394907316253] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]    (308.75,164) -- (392.64,143.52) ;
\draw [shift={(397.5,142.33)}, rotate = 526.28] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (14.29,-6.86) -- (0,0) -- (14.29,6.86) -- cycle    ;
%Shape: Donut [id:dp6846402688267834] 
\draw   (81.5,164) .. controls (81.5,108.77) and (98.18,64) .. (118.75,64) .. controls (139.32,64) and (156,108.77) .. (156,164) .. controls (156,219.23) and (139.32,264) .. (118.75,264) .. controls (98.18,264) and (81.5,219.23) .. (81.5,164)(72.5,164) .. controls (72.5,103.8) and (93.21,55) .. (118.75,55) .. controls (144.29,55) and (165,103.8) .. (165,164) .. controls (165,224.2) and (144.29,273) .. (118.75,273) .. controls (93.21,273) and (72.5,224.2) .. (72.5,164) ;
%Shape: Axis 2D [id:dp8209371942963568] 
\draw  (78.57,164) -- (480.33,164)(118.75,24.5) -- (118.75,179.5) (473.33,159) -- (480.33,164) -- (473.33,169) (113.75,31.5) -- (118.75,24.5) -- (123.75,31.5)  ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9986252650298479] 
\draw    (118.75,164) -- (38.75,264.44) ;
\draw [shift={(37.5,266)}, rotate = 308.53999999999996] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-4.9) .. controls (6.95,-2.3) and (3.31,-0.67) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.67) and (6.95,2.3) .. (10.93,4.9)   ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp709019453920531] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (76.58,209.59) .. controls (76.51,209.37) and (76.64,209.14) .. (76.86,209.07) -- (84.31,206.94) .. controls (84.54,206.88) and (84.77,207) .. (84.83,207.23) -- (92.27,233.18) .. controls (92.33,233.41) and (92.2,233.64) .. (91.98,233.7) -- (84.53,235.84) .. controls (84.31,235.9) and (84.08,235.77) .. (84.01,235.55) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp44607882852530323] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (147.31,97.84) .. controls (147.25,97.63) and (147.39,97.41) .. (147.6,97.36) -- (154.77,95.6) .. controls (154.98,95.55) and (155.2,95.68) .. (155.25,95.9) -- (161.69,122.16) .. controls (161.75,122.37) and (161.61,122.59) .. (161.4,122.64) -- (154.23,124.4) .. controls (154.02,124.45) and (153.8,124.32) .. (153.75,124.1) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8011775407671766] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 74; blue, 74 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (118.75,164) -- (85.96,218.81) ;
\draw [shift={(84.42,221.39)}, rotate = 300.89] [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 74; blue, 74 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (14.21,-4.28) .. controls (9.04,-1.82) and (4.3,-0.39) .. (0,0) .. controls (4.3,0.39) and (9.04,1.82) .. (14.21,4.28)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da30073330719810465] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 74; blue, 74 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (118.75,164) -- (149.94,112.57) ;
\draw [shift={(151.5,110)}, rotate = 481.24] [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 74; blue, 74 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (14.21,-4.28) .. controls (9.04,-1.82) and (4.3,-0.39) .. (0,0) .. controls (4.3,0.39) and (9.04,1.82) .. (14.21,4.28)   ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp5131849801327677] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (114.25,164) .. controls (114.25,161.51) and (116.26,159.5) .. (118.75,159.5) .. controls (121.24,159.5) and (123.25,161.51) .. (123.25,164) .. controls (123.25,166.49) and (121.24,168.5) .. (118.75,168.5) .. controls (116.26,168.5) and (114.25,166.49) .. (114.25,164) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da23183967668813366] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}]  (154.5,110) -- (308.75,164) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8296397184934552] 
\draw    (90.5,100.33) -- (118.75,164) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da3042917546526054] 
\draw    (234.5,179.33) -- (306.5,179.33) ;
\draw [shift={(309.5,179.33)}, rotate = 180] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8852247752349167] 
\draw    (122.5,179.33) -- (215.5,179.33) ;
\draw [shift={(119.5,179.33)}, rotate = 0] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da42460233641055156] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}]  (84.42,221.39) -- (308.75,164) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9037440476041276] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 126; green, 211; blue, 33 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=2.25]    (308.75,164) -- (418.5,163.36) ;
\draw [shift={(423.5,163.33)}, rotate = 539.6700000000001] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 126; green, 211; blue, 33 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (14.29,-6.86) -- (0,0) -- (14.29,6.86) -- cycle    ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp8200585017632998] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (304.25,164) .. controls (304.25,161.51) and (306.26,159.5) .. (308.75,159.5) .. controls (311.24,159.5) and (313.25,161.51) .. (313.25,164) .. controls (313.25,166.49) and (311.24,168.5) .. (308.75,168.5) .. controls (306.26,168.5) and (304.25,166.49) .. (304.25,164) -- cycle ;

% Text Node
\draw (229,122) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$r$};
% Text Node
\draw (99,101.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$R$};
% Text Node
\draw (164,91.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$dq_{2}$};
% Text Node
\draw (97,215.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$dq_{1}$};
% Text Node
\draw (219,174) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$x$};
% Text Node
\draw (454,169.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$x$};
% Text Node
\draw (126,19.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$y$};
% Text Node
\draw (40,232.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$z$};
% Text Node
\draw (281,134.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$P( x,0,0)$};
% Text Node
\draw (243,145.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\theta$};
% Text Node
\draw (362.13,164.07) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\theta$};
% Text Node
\draw (343,187.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$d\vec{\mathbf E}_{2}$};
% Text Node
\draw (365,115.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$d\vec{\mathbf E}_{1}$};
% Text Node
\draw (417,140.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$d\vec{\mathbf E}_{x}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Ring uniformly charged.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Very nice, you are going to finish convincing me to learn how to use `Mathcha`. How long did it take you with this software to make this beautiful drawing?

Comment: @AndréC Ahahahah. Thank you and when I have read your comment I have smiled. I would like to communicate that I am not promoting Mathcha as a tool but only helping users who do not have a MWE to create a design by themselves if they do not have the specific skills. Mathcha is very similar to Geogebra: it provides drawings with a long and approximate code differently from what you do with TikZ.I always liked to draw but if you look at the drawing there are some details that should be arranged by hand.

Comment: @AndréC  Some mistakes in the drawing have been carefully hidden. :-) It took me between 30 and 40 minutes to create this drawing. More I use it and more I realize that there are settings I didn't know about.